# Python library to access the Closure Compiler Service API

Tags: python, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to integrate the closure compiler into my deploy process. I have come accross [this  online tool](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) which allows me to generate some javascript from the required components. I see that the tool can be accessed via an [API](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref?csw=1), so that is what I want to integrate into my deploy scripts.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel, and was wondering if there is an already available python wrapper for this API. The [examples](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial1) provided are very low-level, and I have not found an alternative.

Can somebody point me to higher-level python library to access the `Goggle Closure Compiler Service API`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples at `developer.google.com` actually use Python, so that's a good starting point.
However, it seems that the API is so small that even the official doc just chooses to use the `urllib` and `httplib` Python built-in modules. Generalizing that logic into a helper function or two really seems like a trivial task.

```
...

params = urllib.urlencode([
    ('js_code', sys.argv[1]),
    ('compilation_level', 'WHITESPACE_ONLY'),
    ('output_format', 'text'),
    ('output_info', 'compiled_code'),
  ])

# Always use the following value for the Content-type header.
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('closure-compiler.appspot.com')
conn.request('POST', '/compile', params, headers)

...
```

See https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial1

**P.S.** You can also peek into https://github.com/danielfm/closure-compiler-cli—it's a command line tool but the source demonstrates how simple the API really is.

So turning the above into a Pythonic API:

```
import httplib
import sys
import urllib
from contextlib import closing


def call_closure_api(**kwargs):
    with closing(httplib.HTTPConnection('closure-compiler.appspot.com')) as conn:
        conn.request(
            'POST', '/compile',
            urllib.urlencode(kwargs.items()),
            headers={"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        )
        return conn.getresponse().read()


call_closure_api(
    js_code=sys.argv[1],
    # feel free to introduce named constants for these
    compilation_level='WHITESPACE_ONLY',
    output_format='text',
    output_info='compiled_code'
)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! You have done in a minute what I was planning to do later today - it would have taken me two minutes hopefully!

Comment: just to let you know, I have created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gonvaled/6840024) based on your code.

Comment: @gonvaled: !! I completely disapprove the use of classes for no reason! if your module is named e.g. `closureapi`, you can just `import closureapi` and use it as an object already: `closureapi.call_closure_api()`.

Comment: I see. Appart from being a question of style, is there any drawback in the use of classes? Do you have any link related to this? For me, it is just clearer, and I can extend the class to add some state in the future in case I need that. For example, I could have a `optimizer = ClosureCompiler(compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS_CL)` by adding the appropiate state to the class.

Comment: Do you have a C# or Java background? Because I don't see how it can make anything clearer; in fact, quite the contrary: it makes it look like there might be intantiation somewhere, or instance state or smth. If you must use a singleton, at least make it a real singleton by e.g. `MyObj = MyObj()` right after the `class MyObj(object):` definition. (also, if you're on 2.x, make sure you inherit from `object` so as to not get an old-style class)

Comment: No java/C++ background. As I mention above, one of the things I like about classes is that I can add state and make the objects more powerful and easy to use. Most of my code is implemented like this, so any time I implement any non-trivial functionality I tend to create classes.

Comment: @gonvaled: My point is exactly that: defaulting to classes is a bad idea... it leads to overuse of classes. If you need to retain state, introduce a `Request` class which you return from your stateless API functions. —classes are not meant as a function grouping mechanism but a mechanism to introduce new (data)types; for grouping, there already exist modules which are perfectly suited for that.